# Android Development Cloud Database

Tags: android, database, cloud

I want to create an android game that needs to store information of each user. I am new in this matter, I do not know how to do it.

I guess that I only need a server with a database, but I am not able to use my personal computer as database server, so is there a way to have a "cloud database" and free if possible?

Please, can somebody guide me with this project?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a variety of cloud providers, including Amazon (the largest), Microsoft, etc.  They aren't free, but Amazon can be fairly cheap for low usage.  Google for AWS for amazon or Azure for Microsoft.

Comment: I saw this while looking http://www.scoreloop.com/ there are some Amazon simpleDB images for highscores http://aws.amazon.com/articles/8829919029640036

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon SimpleDB is a non-relational database for storage of smaller, non-structural data. Amazon SimpleDB has restricted storage size to 10GB per domain. Amazon SimpleDB offers simplicity and flexibility. SimpleDB automatically indexes all data. Amazon SimpleDB pricing is based on your actual box usage. You can store any UTF-8 string data in Amazon SimpleDB.

http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/
http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/simpledb/
http://aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-SimpleDB
http://www.sdbexplorer.com/

Answer (score 0):

NuoDB is a disseminated cloud database that is built on original emergent architecture with full support for SQL and ACID guarantees.  It’s an elastically scalable distributed database that provides developers and administrators with single intuitive interface for centrally monitoring deployments. The NuoDB cloud database ships with full support for Node.JS, Ruby, PHP, Java, .NET, and C++. It's the ideal database for high-performance Cloud, datacenter, mobile, and SaaS applications.